# Using OpenKinect on Raspberry pi in python

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, openkinect

I am very new to raspberry pi and python.
I am trying write a progam using python on raspberry pi to use the Kinect. I aim to install OpenKinect on Raspberry pi.
So far I have done:

```
apt-cache search OpenKinect
sudo apt-get install python-freenect
sudo apt-get update
```

Next i tried writing a code in python from this link https://github.com/OpenKinect/libfreenect/blob/master/wrappers/python/demo_cv_async.py

When i try to run the programe, it says that

```
error in line 5, 
import cv.
ImportError:no module named cv.
```

I am not sure if i have installed all the necessary files. I am also not sure what i have done wrong.
I also have been trying to look for tutorials on installing and using OpenKinect.

Comment: i have tried following the steps in this website (http://www.neuroforge.co.uk/index.php/kinect-depth-map-with-python-and-opencv)
however the following commands failed during my attempt
 `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:arne-alamut/freenect
 sudo python setup.py install`

When i run freenect-glview, i get the following error messages
`Number of deviced found:1
GL thread
write reg 0x0105 <= 0x00
freeglut(freenect-glview): OpenGL GLX extension not supported by display ':o.o'`

Comment: Hey @user2306271 it looks like you're not an avid SOF user but I'm curious, did you make any headway with this??

Answer (score 1):

Congradtulations on starting python! That sounds like a complicated project to start on. You should probably try doing the tutorial first at python.org.  I particularily like the google video tutorials (if you are a classroom kind of person): http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tKTZoB2Vjuk

After that you can dig into more detailed stuff :)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you still dont have opencv package for python. Try to install it:

`sudo apt-get install python-opencv`

Comment: I'm trying to install python-opencv. however i get error saying the packages are unable to be authenticated. and when i say install without verifications,  it sys faild to fetch from http:/mirrordirector.raspbian.org/.........

Comment: Im, sorry i have solved the problem. i had forgot to log on to the internet

Comment: With regards to import frame_convert, i think i am suppose to write a code same as this link 
https://github.com/OpenKinect/libfreenect/blob/master/wrappers/python/frame_convert.py

Now when i run the code openkinect code, i get an error (Depth:9107):Gtk-WARNING **: cannot open display

Comment: Do you have x server started?

Comment: i did not do -startx when i got that error. when i use startx, the program loads but no images appear.

Answer (score 0):

The OpenGL or GTK-Warning: Cannot open display. Or the other one you stated
    Number of deviced found:1 GL thread write reg 0x0105 <= 0x00 freeglut(freenect-glview):
    OpenGL GLX extension not supported by display ':o.o'
is because freenect does not support OpenGL. It probably uses EGL.

> bmwesting (Brandt) wrote:
>   "The freenect library provides a demo for the Kinect called glview. The glview program will > not work with the Pi because the program is written using OpenGL. The Raspberry Pi only supports GLES through EGL.
>
> It seems like you will be able to use libfreenect to grab the depth stream and rgb stream, > but will be unable to run the demo program because it uses the incorrect graphics API."

If you read through that thread, it should show the alternatives (i.e. ASUS XTion instead of Kinect). They reach 30fps at high (~ 1024x800) resolution for depth data if using console output mode. I plan to go for Xtion now too - and I hope to get deactivate as much as possible from the USB bus (as this seems to be the bottleneck, for the Kinect too I think).

Comment: Thank you.. I think as it turns out kinect cant be used with the pi yet... i am now trying kinect with the beaglebone.. hope i will be able to succeed with beaglbone

Answer (score 0):

When you install OpenCV using `apt-get install python-opencv` you are installing version 2. However, you can still use the methods from version 1 by doing so:

```
import cv2.cv as cv
```